# Rails is rendering views very slowly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm still really new to Rails and working on a practice project lab and I ran into an issue where the view was rendering really slow.
Any and all help would be appreciated!

I also received this error:

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  
app/models/blogger.rb:23:in `popular_post'
app/views/bloggers/show.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_bloggers_show_html_erb__247812415140953454_70240453389320'
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.6'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'faker'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

My classes are Blogger, Destination, and Post (`Blogger -< Post >- Destination`). Below is the code for the Blogger model, show page, and controller (I didn't work on code for anything else yet, except the Blogger index but works and is just a list)

**blogger.rb**

```
class Blogger < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :destinations
    has_many :posts, through: :destinations
    validates :name, uniqueness: true
    validates :age, numericality: { greater_than: 0, message: ": You're Too Young" }
    validates :bio, length: { :minimum => 30 }

    def self.average_age
        ages = self.all.sum do |blogger|
            blogger.age
        end
        (ages / self.all.count)
    end

    def total_likes
        self.posts.sum do |post|
            post.likes
        end
    end

    def popular_post
        self.posts.max_by do |a|
            a.likes
        end
    end

    def top_five
        self.destinations.sort_by do |destination|
            destination.post_count
        end.take(5)
    end
end
```

**blogger show page**

```
<h1> <%= @blogger.name %> </h1>

<br />
<p> Age: <%= @blogger.age %> </p>
<br />
<br />
<p> Bio: <%= @blogger.bio %> </p>
<br />


<br />

<%= link_to @blogger.popular_post.title, post_path(@blogger.popular_post) %>

<br />
<%= @blogger.top_five %>
```

**blogger controller**

```
class BloggersController < ApplicationController
   
    def index
        @bloggers = Blogger.all
    end

    def show
        @blogger = Blogger.find(params[:id])
    end
    

    def new
        @blogger = Blogger.new
    end

    def create
        @blogger = Blogger.create(blogger_params) 
        if @blogger.valid?
            @blogger.save
            redirect_to blogger_path(@blogger)
        else
            flash[:my_errors] = @blogger.errors.full_messages
            redirect_to new_blogger_path
            # render :new
        end
    end
    
    private

    def blogger_params
        params.require(:blogger).permit(:name, :bio, :age)
    end
    
    
    
end
```

Comment: can you please show the post.rb too?

Comment: Is it "very slowly", or "not at all, because it raises a `SystemStackError`"?

Comment: You haven't shown us the full stack trace (in particular, which part is getting stuck in a recursive loop and causing a stack overflow??), nor the full code (in particular, what's in `post.rb`?), so it's hard to make a guess at the root cause of the problem.

Comment: To fix this problem you might need to understand what this error actually means. This error is caused by a recursive call to some method that does not stop being called. Have a look at https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/SystemStackError.html. You need to figure out what method is causes this error. The error message says that it starts at line 23 in blogger.rb in the method popular_post. That is where a.likes is called where a is a Post object. So I guess you need to have a look at the likes method in the Post class.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to modify this method

```
def popular_post
        self.posts.max_by do |a|
            a.likes
        end
    end
```

`max_by` is a method for an Enumerable class and you call it on a Post class, so this will not work properly. I would suggest that you use something like `posts.order('likes DESC').first` if `likes` is an Integer.

Also tiny hint you don't need to use all this `self` in an object and in class methods. Rails would assume that you call it on an object if this is an object method or you call it on a relation if this is a class method.

Answer (score 0):

The methods `total_likes`, `popular_post` and `top_five` all work by assuming your associations are "arrays" (enumerations). While this works, definitally for smaller examples, it is less optimal. Because working on an array also requires the complete array to be loaded from the database first, and then do your calculations locally on a complete set (in memory). A database is optimally suited to perform such tasks (querying).

For instance, `top_five` can better be written to sort on the database and then only fetch the 5 first (most popular).

```
def top_five
  destinations.order(post_count: :desc).limit(5)
end
```

(this is assuming that `:post_count` is an actual field in the database.

Similarly we can improve the other methods:

```
def total_likes
  posts.sum(:likes)
end
```

just use the database: this will start a single query to return the sum of likes for all the posts of the blogger.

```
def popular_post
  posts.order(likes: :desc).limit(1).first
end
```

We sort on descending likes and the select the first one. The `limit 1` tells we only want to retrieve one item, but this still returns an array, so we want the first returned item.

This should improve your performance.